# Torsors under non-abelian group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \rightarrow Y$ be an immersion of smooth geometrically connected varieties over a number field $k$. Let $G$ be a finite étale non-abelian group scheme. Are there known cases where we have an isomorphism $H^1(Y,G) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^1(X,G)$ of étale cohomology groups?

Note that the above map is defined by pull-backs and hence is always injective. When $G$ is abelian, there are known situations where the isomorphism holds. For example, when $X$ is a smooth projective curve with a $k$-rational point and $Y$ is its Jacobian variety. Another case is when $Y$ is a smooth projective curve and $X$ is the affine curve given by removing a closed point of $Y$.

Comment: There is no reason for that map to be injective, even with $G$ abelian: take $X=\operatorname{Spec}k $.

Comment: @abx so what sufficient condition am I missing for it to be injective? What if $X$ is dense open in $Y$, is it enough? I admit I was hasty in my generalization.

Comment: Yes, $X$ open dense should be enough. But I think you should make clear whether you are interested in open immersions or closed ones, these are completely different situations.

Comment: @abx I didn't know they would be different, in my examples, one is an open immersion while the other is closed. Could you roughly explain why, or direct me to some references?

Comment: Your question can be rephrased in terms of etale fundamental groups: By using the $\pi_1$ version of the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, you can get many examples of closed immersions for which the statement holds. For open immersions, the statement will hold if the complement of $Y$ in $X$ is of codimension at least two (by purity). Another example is the inclusion of affine space in projective space (since the etale fundamental group is trivial for both).

Comment: @naf Do you know how the rephrased question would look like? I've look through the literature but there is little to no references that specifically consider $H^1(Y,G)$ for $G$ that is non-abelian. In other words (if I'm not wrong), how do we relate the etale fundamental group to unramified non-abelian coverings of a variety? More specifically, of a smooth projective curve?

Comment: Unramified $G$-coverings correspond to homomomorphisms from $\pi_1$ to G (up to $G$-conjugacy). This is elementary, first think about the corresponding statement in topology, i.e., in the setting of covering spaces. As far as curves are concerned, if you remove a point from a smooth (projective) curve then the map will almost never be surjective for non-abelian $G$.